# How to allow CountDownTimer to continue running by using NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, countdown, countdowntimer

i want to count down 23 hours. my code works perfectly to count down, however it doesn't work when i quit the app or switch to another viewcontroller/ page within the application

i would like to have it running even though the app is closed and switched to another view controller by using NSUserDefaults

please help, i can provide more code if you need

```
-(void) timerRun {


    secondCount = secondCount - 1;
    int hours = (secondCount/ 3600) % 24;
    int minuts = (secondCount / 60) % 60;
    int seconds = secondCount % 60;


    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d:%2d", hours, minuts, seconds];

    countdownLabel.text = timerOutput;

    if (secondCount == 0) {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
        countdownTimer = nil;

    }

}

-(void) setTimer {

    secondCount = 82800;
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



}


- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {



    [self setTimer];





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add countdownTimer to the runloop:

```
-(void) setTimer 
{
    secondCount = 82800;
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self
    selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:countdownTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

- If you close manually the app, your main runloop will stop running and also your timer.
- If the app is in background, it will work for 10 minutes approx, unless you have some background mode enabled. (location)
- Take care in case your selector is called and your View Controller target has been destroyed.

Comment: thanks for answering. it works in the background, but i also need it to be working after going to another view controller

Comment: @Katie It should just keep working after you come back from another controller, if you're coming back to the same instance.

Comment: are you initializing the timer in viewwillappear?

Comment: also,  set a breakpoint in   "-(void) dealloc"  and check if the viewcontroller has been destroyed when going to another view controllers.

Comment: no. i don't have both viewwillappear and -(void) dealloc. please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the countdown end time instead of the number of seconds.  You can get the end time by calculating the current date plus the number of seconds.

Store the end time in NSUserDefaults.

Your view controller can load this value and reset the timer to update the label.

Also, by storing the end time in NSUserDefaults, you'll have this value when you app starts up again.  You can also set a UILocalNotification to let the user know the count down has finished.

Comment: very clear answer, can you please provide me the code as i am new to this?

Comment: can you please provide the code for me ? @bbarnhart